# How to add support for bluetooth key board support in iOS applications

Tags: ios, bluetooth, keyboard

Using the `(NSArray *)keyCommands` I am able to get key events for all alpha numeric characters, symbols etc. I have tried by subclassing the `UIApplication` and overriding the `(NSArray *)keyCommands method`

```
 -(NSArray *)keyCommands{

    UIKeyCommand *cmdF1    = [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",asciicode] modifierFlags:0 action:@selector(handleShortcut:)];

    ........

    return @[cmdF1,cmdF2....];
  }
```

In my application I need the F1 to F12 Key presses, also Home, End, PageUp key presses in my application. Does any any public api is available to do this? Can we connect key board by using other blue tooth services?